# no intent to view jpg on honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, jpeg, actionview

Here's a bit of code which works fine on phones:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(IMAGEURI, "image/jpg");
startActivity(intent);
```

which on Honeycomb (3.0 and 3.1) throws this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25629): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/images/media/282 typ=image/jpg }
```

Really? There's no application to view jpg on honeycomb? Really? Has anyone been able to do this properly on a tablet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MIME type for JPEG is `image/jpeg`. You have `image/jpg`.

Comment: Thank you! image/jpg worked just fine on phones. image/jpeg works on both phones and tablets.